# Using Jackson to parse a escaped json to JsonNode

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, deserialization

I want to parse an escaped child json within a parent json. Right now I am using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` to first unescape the string. Then I am passing the unescaped string to `objectMapper.readTree` to get a JsonNode object.

```
{
    "fileName": "ParentJson",
    "child": "{\"fileName\":\"ChildJson\",\"Description\":\"Extract string value at child node and convert child json to JsonNode object using only Jackson.\"}"
}
```

When I use Jackson and read the value of `child` node, it adds quotes around it. I don't know if this is an expected behavior. So I have to remove those quotes first.

```
String childString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(parent.get("child").toString());
childString = StringUtils.removeStart(StringUtils.removeEnd(childString, "\"") , "\"");
JsonNode child = objectMapper.readTree(childString);
```

I feel like there should be a better way to handle this use case, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
    String sampleText = "{\n"
        + "    \"fileName\": \"ParentJson\",\n"
        + "    \"child\": \"{\\\"fileName\\\":\\\"ChildJson\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"Extract string value at child node and convert child json to JsonNode object using only Jackson.\\\"}\"\n"
        + "}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode parentJson = objectMapper.readTree(sampleText);
    JsonNode childNode = parentJson.get("child");
    String childText = childNode.asText();
    JsonNode childJson = objectMapper.readTree(childText);
    System.out.println(childJson);
    System.out.println("fileName    = " + childJson.get("fileName").asText());
    System.out.println("Description = " + childJson.get("Description").asText());
```

Comment: Okay! Let me try this. Is there a difference between `.toString()` and `.asText()`?

Comment: Yes - `.toString()` gives you the JSON representation and `asText()` gives you the actual value if the node is a text node.